# PHP - Why is reading this csv file using so much memory, how can I improve my code?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, laravel

Situation is that I need to import a fairly large csv file (approx 1/2 million records - 80mb) to a mysql database. I know I could do this from the command line but I need I UI so the client can do it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

$field_maps = array();

foreach (Input::get() as $field => $value){
if ('fieldmap_' == substr($field, 0, 9) && $value != 'unassigned'){
    $field_maps[str_replace('fieldmap_', null, $field)] = $value;
    }
}
$file = app_path().'/../uploads/'.$client.'_'.$job_number.'/'.Input::get('file');

$result_array = array();
$rows = 0;
$bulk_insert_count = 1000; 
if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    $header = fgetcsv($handle);
    $data_map = array();
    foreach ($header as $k => $th){
        if (array_key_exists($th, $field_maps)){
             $data_map[$field_maps[$th]] = $k;
        }
    }

    $tmp_rows_count = 0;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000)) !== FALSE) {
        $row_array = array();

        foreach ($data_map as $column => $data_index){
            $row_array[$column] = $data[$data_index];
        }

        $result_array[] = $row_array;
        $rows++;
        $tmp_rows_count++;

        if ($tmp_rows_count == $bulk_insert_count){
            Inputs::insert($result_array);
            $result_array = array();
            if (empty($result_array)){
                echo '*************** array cleared *************';
            }
            $tmp_rows_count = 0;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
print('done');
```

I am currently working on a local vagrant box, when I try to run the above locally it process almost all the rows of the csv file and then dies shortly before the end (no error) but it gets up to the boxes memory limit of 1.5Gb.

I suspect some of what I have done in the above code is unnecessary, e.g. but I thought by building up and inserting a limited number of rows I would reduce memory use but it hasn't done enough.

I suspect this would probably work on the live server with more memory available but I cannot believe that it has to take 1.5Gb of memory to process an 80mb file, there must be a better approach. Any help much appreciated

Comment: Consider using LOAD DATA INFILE instead, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this problem once, this solved it for me:

```
DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();
```

Info in the docs about it: http://laravel.com/docs/database#query-logging